# How do I sort the following table & get those top5- 5 recoreds,top20- twenty records?

Tags: php, mysql, database

This query giving strange result:

```
    SELECT `user_id`,`rankType`
    FROM `ranks`
    WHERE `user_id` =23
    AND (`rankType` = "top5"
    OR `rankType` = "top20")
    ORDER BY rankType
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

here the [**SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44c4a/1/0).

Want I am trying to achieve is:

1)To get only 5 records of top5 rank type, 20 records of rank type top20

2)I want to show the result in `ascending order` of **rank type**.(but if you see in the demo fiddle it's showing apposite, `may be it is only considering 2 from 20 & 5`)

Comment: Database you are using is called mysql, not mysqli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(SELECT `id`,`user_id`,`rankType`
FROM `ranks`
WHERE `user_id` =23
AND `rankType` = "top5"
ORDER BY rankType
LIMIT 0, 5)

union 

(SELECT `id`,`user_id`,`rankType`
FROM `ranks`
WHERE `user_id` =23
AND `rankType` = "top20"
ORDER BY rankType
LIMIT 0, 20)
```

If later on you want to add another set of sorting/filtering columns, wrap it all into something like

```
select * from ( /* previous query goes here */ ) tt
where id > 100
order by id
```

Note that `ranktype` is varchar, so it's sorted lexicographically, so top20 < top5. You'll have to employ natural sorting or some other means to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `id`,`user_id`,`rankType`
FROM `ranks`
WHERE `user_id` =23
AND `rankType` = "top5" limit 5
union
SELECT `id`,`user_id`,`rankType`
FROM `ranks`
WHERE `user_id` =23
AND `rankType` = "top20" limit 20
```

Comment: Yes, it seems we both posted at the same time but he was a bit quicker!

Answer (score 0):

Your result is actually in ascending order, since column rank_type is of `varchar` type top20 comes first than top5 as in string comparison.

If you only want to deal between top5 and top20, a dirty solution could be:

```
ORDER BY rankType desc
```

Comment: No because I have to deal with other type of ranks as well

Answer (score 0):

One possibility without doing two queries and UNIONing them:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(rankType,'top5,top20')
```